# How do I position modal according to mouse or element?

Tags: css, reactjs, styling, simplemodal

I have made a react-project where you can search movie titles in an API. It returns all the movies that correspond to your search and presents a list. So far so good.

Each list element has a button that opens a modal with extended info. My problem is styling. If I scroll down the list and click on a movie, its modal opens at the top of the page.

How do I get each modal to open according to the position of the mouse or the button-element?

This is my styling so far:

```
.modal {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.753);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.inner-modal {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: black;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 40px;
}

.modal-poster {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 30px;
}
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for a popover solution and not modal.  A modal is meant to cover or block the whole viewport. See if you can use something like this https://littlebits.github.io/react-popover

Answer (score 1):

#### You can do it using JavaScript. In order to accomplish that you need to:

##### 1. Know which element you are targeting

There are several ways to know which element you are targeting, you can for example set a data attribute on your **Movie** element:
`<Movie data-movie-id={movie.id} />`

##### 2. Compute his position on the page.

Set the clicked movie id on your page component state, and find the clicked movie element on the page in a `useEffect`.

```
  const [clickedMovieId, setClickedMovieId] = useState<string|null>(null)
  const [modalTopOffset, setModalTopOffset] = useState<number>(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!clickedMovieId) {
      return
    }
    // retrieve the element in the DOM based on the data attribute defined in step 1.
    const movieElement = document.querySelector(`[data-movie-id='${clickedMovieId}']`) as HTMLElement | null
    // set the element offset from the top needed for the modal.
    setModalTopOffset(movieElement?.offsetTop ?? 0)
  }, [clickedMovieId])
```

##### 3. Define the **Modal** top position style based on `modalTopOffset`.

Create your own modal component or import it from a library. It might look like this:

```
    <Modal
      {...otherModalProps}
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '50%',
        transform: 'translateX(-50%)',
        // position the modal at the same offset as the clicked Movie element.
        top: `${modalTopOffset}px`,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Modal>
```

You just need to define some extra style as shown on the above code in order to set the element top positioning, based on `modalTopOffset` that we are computed in the `useEffect` on step 2.